# browser livereload not working when using grunt-contrib-watch with combination of grunt-express

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, livereload

I started to test the livereload ability of the combination of grunt watch plugin (grunbt-contrib-watch) and grunt express server (grunt-express).
my directory has a gruntfile.js file in the root directory, all npm modules are installed in the npm_modules folder and there is a folder called "build" that contains one html file.
3 packages where installed using npm :

1. grunt
2. grunt-contrib-watch
3. grunt-express

### They are working fine. the watch plugin is watching the html file successfully and the server is running at localhost:3000, the only problem is that the livereload property of express plugin is not working when i change the HTML file. I can't figure out why?

my guntfile.js looks like bellow:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
        html: {
            files: ['build/*.html'],
            tasks: []
        }
    },
    express: {
        all: {
            options: {
                bases: 'build',
                livereload: true,
                open: 'http://localhost:3000'
            }
        }
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express');
grunt.registerTask('start', ['express','watch']);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

on watch config add:

```
 options: {
          nospawn: true,
          atBegin: true,
        }
```

ref link: http://thanpol.as/grunt/Grunt-with-express-server-and-Livereload/

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't solve the problem. when I added both options, it starts the server but shows infinite times of a warning saying that it can not read property length of undefined.